# How to mirror schema in Spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a data frame which has schema of another data frame .

This is my code where I want to create mirror schema .

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


val getFFActionParent =  udf { (FFAction: String) => 
    if (FFAction=="Insert") "I|!|"
    else if (FFAction=="Overwrite") "I|!|"
    else "D|!|" 
}

val getFFActionChild =  udf { (FFAction: String) => 
    if (FFAction=="Insert") "I|!|"
    else if (FFAction=="Overwrite") "O|!|"
    else "D|!|" 
}

val dfContentEnvelope = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "env:ContentEnvelope").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/XML")


val dfContentItem = dfContentEnvelope.withColumn("column1", explode(dfContentEnvelope("env:Body.env:ContentItem"))).select("column1.*")
val FinancialSourceDF=dfContentItem.select($"env:Data.sr:Source.*",getFFActionParent($"_action").as("FFAction")).filter($"env:Data.sr:Source._organizationId".isNotNull).drop("sr:Auditors")
val FinancialSourceDFFinal=dfContentItem.select($"env:Data.sr:Source._organizationId".as("organizationId"), $"env:Data.sr:Source._sourceId".as("sourceId"), $"env:Data.sr:Source.*",getFFActionParent($"_action").as("FFAction")).filter($"env:Data.sr:Source._organizationId".isNotNull).drop("sr:Auditors")
```

The schema will be mirrored from below data frame

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSource/INCR")
val header1 = rdd1.filter(_.contains("Source.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val MirrorSchemaschema1 = StructType(header1.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
```

Here I am trying to create mirror schema but not able to create it ..

```
val FinancialSourceSaveDF=FinancialSourceDF.select(FinancialSourceDF.columns.filter(x => !x.equals("sr:Auditors")).map(x => col(x).as(x.replace("_", "Source.").replace("sr:", ""))): _*)

FinancialSourceSaveDF.select(MirrorSchemaschema1.fieldNames.map(col): _*).show(false)
```

NOTE:The columns in `FinancialSourceSaveDF` data frame may change i.e sometime all columns will be present sometime some of them will be present .
null value will be filled for the non present columns .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get `dfContentItem`, you can simply `select` the *elements* you require from `Source` *struct* and *rename columns using `alias`* as below.

```
val dfContentItem = dfContentEnvelope.withColumn("column1", explode(dfContentEnvelope("env:Body.env:ContentItem"))).select("column1.*")
val dfType=dfContentItem.select($"env:Data.sr:Source.*", $"_action".as("FFAction|!|"))
val temp = dfType.select(dfType.columns.filter(x => !x.equals("sr:Auditors")).map(x => col(x).as(x.replace("_", "Source_").replace("sr:", ""))): _*)
```

*you can used the udf function you've mentioned as you prefer*

Once you know you have all the *columns* required for `schema` *columns* read from

```
Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
```

Now **Your Main problem is that you don't know how many column names might be missing in the *new dataframe* from the *referenced dataframe schema***. For that you can find the difference between the column names and use `foldLeft` function to populate the missing columns with `null` values as

```
val diff = schema.fieldNames.diff(temp.schema.fieldNames)
val finaldf = diff.foldLeft(temp){(temp2df, colName) => temp2df.withColumn(colName, lit(null))}
```

You can just `select` to get the *mirror schema* as below

```
finaldf.select(schema.fieldNames.map(col): _*).show(false)
```

You should have output as

```
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------+----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
|Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime         |SourceTypeCode|DocumentId|Dcn |DocFormat|StatementDate          |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|ContainsPreliminaryData|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|ContainsRestatement|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|ThirdPartySourceCode|ThirdPartySourcePriority|SourceTypeId|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|FFAction|!||
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------+----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
|4295906830           |344            |20171111T17:00:00+00:00|10K           |null      |null|null     |20171030T00:00:00+00:00|false                    |false                  |20171030T00:00:00+00:00    |1.0                       |false              |300                    |SS                  |1                       |3011835     |1000716240            |Overwrite  |
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------+----+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful